# Incorrect results with vDSP_conv()

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I am getting inconsitent results when attempting to do convolution using vDSP_conv() from Accelerate when compared to the MATLAB implementation. There have been a couple of StackOverflow posts about weird results when using this function to calculate convolution, however as far as I can tell, I am using the framework correctly and have incorporated the suggestions from the other Stack Overflow posts. Here is my code:

```
public func conv(x: [Float], k: [Float]) -> [Float] {  
    let resultSize = x.count + k.count - 1
    var result = [Float](count: resultSize, repeatedValue: 0)
    let kEnd = UnsafePointer<Float>(k).advancedBy(k.count - 1)
    let xPad: [Float] = [Float](count: (2*k.count)+1, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    let xPadded = x + xPad
    vDSP_conv(xPadded, 1, kEnd, -1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(resultSize), vDSP_Length(k.count))
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am doing the correct zero padding as specified in the Accelerate framework documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_conv)

I defined two test arrays `A: [Float] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` and `B: [float] = [1, 0, 0]`.

In MATLAB, when I run `conv(A, B)`, I get `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

However, when I run the above vDSP `conv()` I get, `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

What is wrong with my implementation? I have gone over this a number of times and looked through all the SO posts that I could find, and still haven't been able to account for this inconsistency.

Beyond that, is there a more efficient method to zero-pad the array then what I have here? In order to keep `x` immutable, I created the new `xPadded` array but there is undoubtedly a more efficient method of performing this padding.

** EDIT **
As suggested by Martin R, I padded `k.count -1` equally at the beginning and end of the array as shown below.

```
public func conv(x: [Float], k: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    let resultSize = x.count + k.count - 1
    var result = [Float](count: resultSize, repeatedValue: 0)
    let kEnd = UnsafePointer<Float>(k).advancedBy(k.count - 1)
    let xPad: [Float] = [Float](count: k.count-1, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    let xPadded = xPad + x + xPad
    vDSP_conv(xPadded, 1, kEnd, -1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(resultSize), vDSP_Length(k.count))

    return result
}
```

Using this code, `conv(A, B)` still returns [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

I am calling the function as shown below:

```
let A: [Float] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
let B: [Float] = [1, 0, 0]
let C: [Float] = conv(A, k: B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MartinR I figured out why my code doesn't work with Arrays. I was writing this code in a project that was using Surge as a linked framework. Surge overloads the `+` operator for [Float] and [Double] arrays so that it becomes element-wise addition of array elements. So when I was doing `x + xPad` it wasn't extending the size of the array as expected, it was simply returning `x` as `xPad` only contained zeros. However, Surge had not overloaded the `+`operator for sequences, so using `Repeat()` successfully extended the array. Thanks for your help - never would have thought to try sequences!

Answer (score 3):

For two arrays `A` and `B` of length `m` and `n`,
the [`vDSP_conv()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_conv) function from the Accelerate framework computes a new array of length `m - n + 1`.

This corresponds to the result of the MATLAB function [`conv()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) with the shape
parameter set to "valid":

> Only those parts of the convolution that are computed without the zero-padded edges. ...

To get the same result as the with "full" convolution from MATLAB
you have to zero-pad the `A` array with `n-1` elements at the beginning and the end, this gives a result array of length `m + n - 1`.

Applied to your function:

```
let xPad = Repeat(count: k.count - 1, repeatedValue: Float(0.0))
let xPadded = xPad + x + xPad
```

Using `Repeat()` might be *slightly* more performant because it
creates a sequence and not an array. But ultimately, a new array
has to be created as an argument to the`vDSP_conv()` function,
so there is not much room for improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. When I pad the array equally with `k.count-1` zeros at the beginning and the end, I get completely incorrect values for the convolution. I've also tried this with various combinations of padding at the beginning and the end. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @RemyPrechelt: For the input arrays A, B in your question, it produces the output `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` which seems to be what you expect. Can you give an example where it does not work? (Input, output and expected output)

Comment: I added the edited code up above, and also added the calling code. Function is still returning a result inconsistent with MATLAB/Octave and Numpy.

Comment: @RemyPrechelt: I have copy/pasted your updated function and test code into my Xcode project, and the result is `C = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`.

Comment: Ok. So this is bizarre. I cleaned the project, and run `conv()` using the code above. I get incorrect values `[1.0, 4.59093e-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.21425e-39]`. However, if I change the definition of `xPad` to use `Repeat`, I get the correct answer of `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`. I've tested this 5 times now with other arrays. My convolution is always shifted over 2 units whenever I declare `xPad` as an array, and is always correct when `xPad` is a sequence. Do you have any insight into this behavior? Is it repeatable on your end?

Comment: @RemyPrechelt: Unfortunately not. Both your exact code and the Repeat version produce exactly the same (correct) output. I have run it repeatedly and in a loop. – Do you compile that as a command-line tool or OS X or iOS App? Simulator or device? Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: I am compiling an XCode framework for iOS. The functions are being called in my unit tests (XCTestCase Class) for the convolution code above. I'm printing the arrays to the debug window from within the test case class during testing.Thanks for all your help on this! Most appreciated!

Comment: Does it work better if you replace the `vDSP_conv(...)` call with `xPadded.withUnsafeBufferPointer { vDSP_conv($0.baseAddress, 1, kEnd, -1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(resultSize), vDSP_Length(k.count)) }` ?

Answer (score 2):

Some clarifications for the next poor soul who stumbles into this:
Apple provides [some sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/DemonstrateConvolution_c.html) on how to use vDSP_conv but it's pretty useless. In fact, it was confusing me because a comment in that code says that the input buffer needs to be padded without specifying where the actual input samples should be placed:

> The SignalLength defined below is used to allocate space, and it is the filter length rounded up to a multiple of four elements and added to the result length.

`SignalLength = (FilterLength+3 & -4u) + ResultLength;`

So, the above formula gives you a different length (bigger) than the `xPad + x + xPad` where xPad is the k.count - 1.

The important thing is where in that padded buffer you copy your input (signal) samples: it needs to be at `k.count - 1`.

So, the above accepted solution works. But if you trust that comment in Apple's example (which BTW doesn't show up in the official docs) then you can do a compromise: use their formula (the SignalLength above) to calculate and allocate the padded buffer (it will be a bit larger) and use the `k.count - 1` (i.e. filter length - 1) as the starting offset for your signal (x in this case). I did this and the results now match ippsConvolve_32f and Matlab.

*(Sorry, this should have been a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that).*